# how to add different content in swiping pages in android

Tags: java, android

I'm using a horizontal paging app but it's a fixed content .I want to have a different content in each section like text or images not 1,2,3 numbers.
I hope you can help me with this.
and this is my code

```
  package com.example.android.horizontalpaging;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
     * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    /**
     * Create the activity. Sets up an {@link android.app.ActionBar} with tabs, and then configures the
     * {@link ViewPager} contained inside R.layout.activity_main.
     *
     * <p>A {@link SectionsPagerAdapter} will be instantiated to hold the different pages of
     * fragments that are to be displayed. A
     * {@link android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener} will also be configured
     * to receive callbacks when the user swipes between pages in the ViewPager.
     *
     * @param savedInstanceState
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Load the UI from res/layout/activity_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.sample_main);

        // Set up the action bar. The navigation mode is set to NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS, which will
        // cause the ActionBar to render a set of tabs. Note that these tabs are *not* rendered
        // by the ViewPager; additional logic is lower in this file to synchronize the ViewPager
        // state with the tab state. (See mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener() and onTabSelected().)
        // BEGIN_INCLUDE (set_navigation_mode)
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        // END_INCLUDE (set_navigation_mode)

        // BEGIN_INCLUDE (setup_view_pager)
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three primary sections
        // of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        // END_INCLUDE (setup_view_pager)

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding tab. We can also use
        // ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have a reference to the Tab.
        // BEGIN_INCLUDE (page_change_listener)
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });
        // END_INCLUDE (page_change_listener)

        // BEGIN_INCLUDE (add_tabs)
        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by the adapter. Also
            // specify this Activity object, which implements the TabListener interface, as the
            // callback (listener) for when this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }
        // END_INCLUDE (add_tabs)
    }

    /**
     * Update {@link ViewPager} after a tab has been selected in the ActionBar.
     *
     * @param tab Tab that was selected.
     * @param fragmentTransaction A {@link android.app.FragmentTransaction} for queuing fragment operations to
     *                            execute once this method returns. This FragmentTransaction does
     *                            not support being added to the back stack.
     */
    // BEGIN_INCLUDE (on_tab_selected)
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, tell the ViewPager to switch to the corresponding page.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }
    // END_INCLUDE (on_tab_selected)

    /**
     * Unused. Required for {@link android.app.ActionBar.TabListener}.
     */
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * Unused. Required for {@link android.app.ActionBar.TabListener}.
     */
    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    // BEGIN_INCLUDE (fragment_pager_adapter)
    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages. This provides the data for the {@link ViewPager}.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    // END_INCLUDE (fragment_pager_adapter)

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        // BEGIN_INCLUDE (fragment_pager_adapter_getitem)
        /**
         * Get fragment corresponding to a specific position. This will be used to populate the
         * contents of the {@link ViewPager}.
         *
         * @param position Position to fetch fragment for.
         * @return Fragment for specified position.
         */
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            Bundle args = new Bundle();

            switch(position){
                case 0:
                    fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
                    args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
                    args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
                    args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
                    args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    break;
            }
            return fragment;
        }
        // END_INCLUDE (fragment_pager_adapter_getitem)

        // BEGIN_INCLUDE (fragment_pager_adapter_getcount)
        /**
         * Get number of pages the {@link ViewPager} should render.
         *
         * @return Number of fragments to be rendered as pages.
         */
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 4;
        }
        // END_INCLUDE (fragment_pager_adapter_getcount)

        // BEGIN_INCLUDE (fragment_pager_adapter_getpagetitle)
        /**
         * Get title for each of the pages. This will be displayed on each of the tabs.
         *
         * @param position Page to fetch title for.
         * @return Title for specified page.
         */
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
                case 3:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
        // END_INCLUDE (fragment_pager_adapter_getpagetitle)
    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply displays dummy text.
     * This would be replaced with your application's content.
     */
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_label";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container, false);
            TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have 3 different classes extending fragment, instead of this DummySectionFragment...

in the method getItem of SectionsPagerAdapter, compare the position, and instantiate one or other fragment class...

The fragment class will have the content you want.

I don't speak English, but I hope I have helped you.

```
public class StudentsFragment extends Fragment { 
//whatever the fragment will do here
}

public class TeachersFragment extends Fragment { 
//whatever the fragment will do here
}

public class ClassesFragment extends Fragment { 
//whatever the fragment will do here
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
     @Override
     public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position) {
         case 0:
             return new StudenstFragment();
         case 1:
             return new TeachersFragment();
         case 2:
             return new ClassesFragment();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but if you perform it in real code I would be grateful

Answer (score 0):

i don't really get what you are trying to do, but i get the main idea XD
why not to use a intent to call the same activity but send a varible which divide the code in diferent actions for example:
first the variable which controls the activity are going to do

```
String num ="";
```

then the button code, depends on how many you want

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new Button onclickListener(){
        public void onClick(){
            //get a default variable in this case String num
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class); num="cero"; intent.putExtra("po", num);
                        CodigoPeticion=2; startActivityForResult (intent,CodigoPeticion); finish(); break;
                }
            }
        });
```

this one to get the String num:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras!= null) {
            num =extras.getString("po");
        }
```

and at last but not least this one to do someting depending the String:

```
if (num.matches("cero")){
            //do something, enable more buttons, disable radiobuttons, etc
        }else if(num.matches("one")){//this string is from another button
            //do something else in the same activity, as you spected enable radiobuttons, show a image, etc
        }else{
            //some textview with a specific title
            TextView.setText("Something's Wrong");
        }
```

hope that helps you, see ya!

Comment: thanks for your answer but i'm using a swipe paging .I want different content in each section for example in section one i want this text " I'm at first section i'm so happy"
and section 2 " This is a section which i'm so so happy :)"
and so on

Comment: ohh now i get it, you mean a tab host!, http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-an-activity-android-with-a-tabhost-view/27990 check it out